# Migrate Vignette CM (Content Manager) content to Oracle UCM

Tags: oracle, migration, content-management, vignette

We're at the start of a project where we need to migrate Vignette CM (version 7.6) content to Oracle UCM (11g).

Some pointers on which tools and approaches to use would be extremely helpful.

It seems to me that you should be able to write an application to export content using the Vignette Content Management SDK (as described in this doc: http://docs.bizbeta.com/docs/vignette/sdk_content_management.pdf). However, I can't quite figure out how to connect to a Vignette CM instance using the above mentioned SDK.

As for the import side of things, I managed to find this link to a Batch Loader product for Oracle UCM.
http://www.fishbowlsolutions.com/StellentSolutions/StellentComponents/EnterpriseBatchloader/fs_entbatchload_webcopy

What other tools are available for importing content into Oracle UCM/WCM? Does Oracle provide a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proventeq has tools for automated migration into Oracle UCM (most versions including 11g). Its called the Proventeq Migration Accelerator, and it does have connectors to migrate Vignette to Oracle UCM ( http://www.proventeq.com/solutions/oracle-ucm-stellent-migration ). It a very versatile rules based migration engine which can be configured to meet any requirements.